What is a common design pattern in Django Model: custom Manager vs custom QuerySet
In Django, I have a model Country. Along with many columns, there is a BooleanField is_deleted. Most of the times, data retrieved from this table will be with filter is_deleted=False, however there are very few times when this filter should not be applied. There may be further filter applied on other columns.
I have two approaches:
Approach 1:
class CountryManager(models.Manager):
    # implements new methods

class ActiveCountryManager(CountryManager):
    get_queryset(self):
        return super().get_queryset().filter(is_deleted__eq=False)
    # Inherits everything else from CountryManager, may overwrite only what is needed

class Country(models.Model):
    # ...
    objects = CountryManager()
    objects_active = ActiveCountryManager()
    # ...

all_countries = Country.objects.all()
active_countries = Country.objects_active.all()

Approach 2:
class CountryQuerySet(models.QuerySet):
    def active(self):
        return self.filter(is_deleted__eq=False)

class CountryManager(models.Manager):
    def get_queryset(self):
        return CountryQuerySet(self.model, using=self._db)

    def active_all():
        return self.get_queryset().active()

class Country(models.Model):
    # ...
    objects = CountryManager()
    # ...

all_countries = Country.objects.all()
active_countries = Country.objects.active_all()

Not sure if I have other approaches.
Which approach should I prefer? I am new to Django, and my app is going to have lots of tables with such columns as is_deleted, so I want it to be standardized, so that it is easy for future developers to follow.
Also, I hope this is the right place to ask this question, and I have intentionally not put it in StackOverflow.
